# In Spring how to configure a queue with multiple conditions

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have configured a queue in my .XML file,in a way that it would b populated after processing records.I need to add a condition to the queue that it becomes active only when queue depth reaches 1000 or delay time is reached.? Is it possible? I am not using jms.

Comment: If not jms, then what specifically are you using for messaging?

Comment: You need to show your configuration and explain more clearly what you mean. Terminology is important; we can't "guess" what you are talking about when you say "queue".